# How do I use LINQPad to do execute batch job?

Tags: batch-processing, linqpad

I recently found that LINQPad can execute shell commands. Can someone show me an example how to use LINQPad queries to execute batch job?

---

Sorry I didn't make my question clear. What I mean is make .linq file become my batch file. That is, schedule a batch job written in .linq file and use LINQPad as the command to execute it.

Answer (score 5):

Just call the batch file using the shell execute command:

```
Util.Cmd (@"c:\batch\MyBatchFile.bat");
```

Comment: I tried to launch IE doesn't work:

Util.Cmd (@"""C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe""");